# Corrupted double-linked list

Tags: java, android, error-handling, libgdx, runtime-error

When running the Java application, after some times, here comes that error:

> *** Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007fd77c2cf640 ***

The correct instruction must set a variable and restart the application.

More information:

Immediately next, the Run-log print out:

> Process finished with exit code 134

I found that the error occurs at this point:

```
private Game game;
private void backToMenu ()
{
    // switch to menu screen
    game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
}
```

exactly at:

```
game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
```

Some imports are:

> import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
>   import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.screens.MenuScreen;

The libgdx version is 1.6.0, the guide says the libgdx version used in the book is 0.1.2 (Learning LibGDX Game Development Second Edition).

I run the desktop version (desktop module) of the application under Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the Google search results for "corrupted double-linked list", the message is a result of an internal assertion error detected in "malloc".  That is the native heap allocation function which is used by native (C / C++) library code.  The error is most likely a consequence of something (in native code) corrupting memory.

This kind of thing should never happen in a "pure Java" application.  Possible causes include:

- A bug in one of your own native libraries.
- A bug in a 3rd-party native library.
- A consequence of corruption cause by using the `Unsafe` class incorrectly.
- A JVM bug.

But the minimal information you have provided does not allow us to diagnose your problem.  (Hint!!)

> The correct instruction must set a variable and restart the application.

It is unlikely that you can fix the problem that way.

---

**UPDATE** - There is still not enough information diagnose this, but when I Googled `libgdx "corrupted double-linked list"`, I got hits where the problem turned out to be due to methods being called on objects after `dispose` had been called.

It is possibly your code doing something like that, or the 3rd-party `MenuScreen` code doing it.

In short, it looks like something is using the `libgdx` wrappers incorrectly.

Comment: Thank's for the reply! I inserted more info in the question.